# "Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address"

Tags: twilio, rasa

I have integrated rasa assistant with twilio to show chat in watsaap messenger.
Currently, when i send the message to the bot this error is coming up.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I faced this issue while trying the Twilio WhatsApp API with test credentials (expecting it to work).

You need to use the LIVE Credentials instead of the Test Credentials. The [test credentials do not support WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials#supported-resources) at time of writing. It will cost you some money per successful API call (because it is a real API call to WhatsApp).

Comment: Life saver. Thank you. I spent a full day trying and sweating with al sorts of articles, i tried different alternatives, tried vonage even SMH,, tried cURL things, Damn

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates the destination (To:) number is not WhatsApp enabled. If that is not the case, you should open a ticket with Twilio via the Twilio console to have them further investigate.

[Twilio could not find a Channel with the From address](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/63007)

Comment: The (To:) number is my watsaap number that i am using. The (from:) number is twilio number that is generated

Comment: So if the To: number is indeed a WhatsApp enabled number (your personal WhatsApp device) and you are unable to send to it, you should open a ticket with Twilio to investigate.